# How can I untokenize a spacy.tokens.token.Token?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, token, spacy

how can I untokenize the output of this code?

class Core:

```
def __init__(self, user_input):
    pos = pop(user_input)
    subject = ""
    for token in pos:
        if token.dep == nsubj:
            subject = untokenize.untokenize(token)
    subject = S(subject)
```

I tried:
https://pypi.org/project/untokenize/

MosesDetokenizer

.join()

But I have this error for my last code (from this post):

```
TypeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object is not iterable
```

This error for .join():

```
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object has no attribute 'join'
```

And for MosesDetokenizer:
    text = u" {} ".format(" ".join(tokens))
TypeError: can only join an iterable

Answer (score 11):

All tokens in spacy keep their context around so all text can be recreated without any loss of data.

In your case, all you have to do is:

```
''.join([token.text_with_ws for token in doc])
```

Since the attribute `text_with_ws` has the token with its corresponding whitespace character if it exists.

Comment: I still have this error: 
su.join([token.text_with_ws for token in subject])
TypeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object is not iterable

Comment: I just realized, in your code, you are saving only a single token as subject

Comment: Yes, can I do something with this? Nothing from internet works :(

Comment: Put the tokens in a list, then join

Comment: Here is my code where I try to check if the subject exist in a list:

class S:
     def __init__(self, subject):
         personal_words = ["I", "ME", "US"]
         er = ["YOU"]
         self.subject = subject
         s = []
         s.append(subject)
         print(s)
         su = ""
         su.join([token.text_with_ws for token in s])
         print(su)
         if any(item in s for item in personal_words):
             print("T1")
         else:
             print("T2")

And here is my output 
I am Ironman
[I]

(I don't know why the code is so hard to read here)

Comment: And here is the error:
TypeError: Argument 'other' has incorrect type (expected spacy.tokens.token.Token, got str)

Answer (score 3):

SpaCy tokens have their doc object associated with them, so this will give you the original sentence as a string:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("I like cake.")
token = doc[0]

print(token.doc) # prints "I like cake."
```

Comment: OK, can you expand on your code? What is `pop`? What is an example input string? I'll revise my code to go from text to token.

Comment: pop = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
An exemple of input is something like: I am Ironman
The program will take the subject I and will create a token. I can send you the code on email, but I don't know how to make it easy to read here

Comment: @polm23 What if I wanted to mutate a token and return back a mutated document? How would I go about that?

Comment: If you have a question please ask a new question rather than asking a question in comments...

Answer (score -1):

@RazvanP
I believe what you need here is to get the following output

```
['I', 'like', 'cake', '.']
```

If yes, here is the code.

```
new_list=[]

doc = nlp("I like cake.")

for i in doc:

    new_list.append(''+i.text+'')

print(new_list)
```

See if this works for you.